# How can I find an error measure based on the horizontal shift of vertical lines?

Tags: image-processing

I have a grayscale image consisting of MxN 1 byte pixels.
The image shows K vertical lines. Each vertical line has the same thickness.

Due to a systematic error each line is imaged in a different horizontal position than the actual position. The horizontal shift differs between lines.

Consider a scenario where there are K=2 lines. This figure shows the position of the imaged lines as red and the correct position as blue:

[image]

We see that the left line is shifted 1 to the right of its actual position and the right line is shifted 2 to the right of its actual position.

In this case I may use $$RMSE=\sqrt{1^2+2^2}$$
as the error of the imaging.

I am looking for an algorithm that automatically calculates such an error/penalty function.
Using this algorithm I will then tune two parameters (using gradient descent or similar) until the error is minimized.

Consider a part of a row in such an image. This figure shows the pixel values and one vertical line as a red rectangle:

[image]

One first step may be to find the center of the vertical line as a fractional horizontal pixel coordinate.

How could I do this?

Having found this I could for each row find a set of K fractional horizontal coordinates representing the K imaged lines:
$$\{x_{imaged_i}\}$$.

I could then perhaps for each imaged line find the distance to the closest actual line: $$d_i=|x_{imaged_i}-x_{actual_i}|$$ and sum up the square of these distances and take the square root?

$$RMSE=\sqrt{\Sigma d_i^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location could be found using a simple weighting of the pixel values:

| Pixel location | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pixel value | 0 | 50 | 255 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| Product | 0 | 1 $\times$ 50 = 50 | 2 $\times$ 255 = 510 | 3 $\times$ 200 = 600 | 4 $\times$ 0 = 0 | 5 $\times$ 0 = 0 |

And then sum the products up and divide by the summed pixel values.

$$
\bar{x} =  \frac{0 + 50 + 510 + 600 + 0 + 0}{0 + 50 + 255 + 200 + 0 + 0} = \frac{1160}{505} = 2.297
$$

The trick will be to decide when one line stops and the other starts.

Comment: Is this a weighted version of the centroid formulae in 1 dimension?

Comment: @Andy Yes, it's just finding the weighted centroid.